# Extern command in c programming

Tags: c, codeblocks, header-files

I'm trying to write a program that prints the Fibonacci sequence. I must use “header.h” and “source.c” files (i can't write the function in the header file).

So I have 3 files:

MAIN

```
// main.c file
#include <stdio.h>
#include "header1.h"

int main(){
    int n=15, i=0;
    printf("Fibonacci series terms are:\n");

    for (int c=1; c<=n; c++ ){
        printf("%d ", fibonacci(i));
        i++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

HEADER

```
// header1.h file
#ifndef header1_h
#define header1_h

extern int fibonacci(int n);

#endif
```

SOURCE

```
// source1.c
#include "header1.h"

int fibonacci(int n){
    if ( n==0 || n==1 )
        return n;
    else
    return fibonacci(n-1) + fibonacci(n-2);
}
```

CodeBlock compiler:

undefined reference to `fibonacci'

error: ld returned 1 exit status

**I think i need to add something to the header file because i don't think he knows where the function is.**

Comment: you probably forgot to add `source1.c` in your project

Comment: The error message does not come from your compiler. It is a linker error. If you have 2 files that hold your code, you must provide both of them to your linker. Otherwise it can simply not find where the implementation is.

Comment: Maybe you did not add the files to your project? Try to add them
 https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-add-h-header-files-in-Code-Blocks

Comment: In Codeblocks you just add everything to the project, both headers + source.

Comment: Ok I just needed to add the files in a project. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the linker, you need to add the file to the project.

Solution:
Add all the files to the project
https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-add-h-header-files-in-Code-Blocks